# How do you build a dynamic where clause for SQL

Tags: sql

I've some sort of design problem. Assume that I have an SQL table with 15 columns and I would like to give the user the ability to query from that table using any of the 15 columns with any combination she wishes.

So I have table T1 with A1 to A15 columns and the user may produce any combination of where clause (and for the sake of simplicity let's just assume that the only valid operator is '=' and 'AND' is the only valid condition) :

```
WHERE A1 = x
```

or

```
WHERE A3 = y AND A4 = Z AND A12 = x
```

or any such combination you may think of.

unfortunately there is not 'IGNORE' value in SQL that tells the engine to well ignore a condition (I'm going to suggest it to my favorite DB) so I need to revert to string concatenation which has many problems.

What is your solution to this?

Thanks,
Eden

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1):

One method you can use is to use a `NULL` value in the parameter to ignore the value:

```
WHERE (A1 = $A1 OR $A1 IS NULL) AND
      (A2 = $A2 OR $A3 IS NULL) AND
      . . .
```

Notes:

- The resulting query cannot use indexes.
- This does not allow comparisons to `NULL`.
- In the above, the parameters should be *placeholders*, not literal values

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `IFNULL()` in mysql or `ISNULL()` in SQL Server.

**MySQL**

```
WHERE A1 = IFNULL(@A1, A1) AND
      A2 = IFNULL(@A2, A2) AND
      . . .
```

**SQL Server**

```
WHERE A1 = ISNULL(@A1, A1) AND
      A2 = ISNULL(@A2, A2) AND
      . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for all columns in SQL Server

```
WHERE A1 = ISNULL(@A1, A1) AND
      A2 = ISNULL(@A2, A2) AND
     . 
     .
     .
```